# Unity Android build error - Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error and have no idea what it means. can someone explain please.

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\Documents\Android SDK\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Documents/Android SDK/android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_
stderr[]
stdout[]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String[] progress_strings, Single progress_value, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/834744/building-android-application-failed-re-package-res.html

Comment: Michael, thanks for the link. It solves the issue. I will put link down as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Gaskill suggested, the solution to this issue was found [here.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/834744/building-android-application-failed-re-package-res.html) What worked for me was adding the version.xml file as suggested in the post.